# I am trying to pass some variables from a form to the next page using session state

Tags: c#

Here is what my code looks like in the first page:

```
 protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            decimal salesPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(txtSalesPrice.Text);
            decimal discountPercent = Convert.ToDecimal(txtDiscountPercent.Text) / 100;

            decimal discountAmount = salesPrice * discountPercent;
            decimal totalPrice = salesPrice - discountAmount;

            lblDiscountAmount.Text = discountAmount.ToString("c");
            lblTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString("c");

            Session.Add("salesPrice", salesPrice);
            Session.Add("discountAmount", discountAmount);
            Session.Add("totalPrice", totalPrice);

        }
    }

    protected void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (Session["salesPrice"] == null)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Click the Calculate button before you confirm.";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("Confirm.aspx");
        }
    }
```

And now I try to capture those variables:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox salesPrice = (TextBox)Session["salesPrice"];
        TextBox discountAmount = (TextBox)Session["discountAmount"];
        TextBox totalPrice = (TextBox)Session["totalPrice"];
```

Comment: What's the question/problem here?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and explain what issue you are having?  Also it appears as though your code formatting got messed up when posting, use the post preview to help with fixing your formatting.

Comment: You are trying to store the whole control. You should probably only store a string or number that you want put into one of the control’s properties (such as `Text`).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code from this:

```
TextBox salesPrice = (TextBox)Session["salesPrice"];
TextBox discountAmount = (TextBox)Session["discountAmount"];
TextBox totalPrice = (TextBox)Session["totalPrice"];
```

to:

```
salesPrice.Text = Session["salesPrice"].ToString();
discountAmount.Text = Session["discountAmount"].ToString();
totalPrice.Text = Session["totalPrice"].ToString();
```

Here, salesPrice, discountAmount, totalPrice are Textboxes. As a good practice, you can check whether the Session["fieldname"] is not null etc..